# Can't find out expected result from Left Join Where & group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table receivable & receive.

table: receivable

```
tranId  roll     month         amount
 1      1111    October-2019    10
 2      1112    October-2019    10
 3      1113    October-2019    10
 4      1114    October-2019    10
 5      1115    October-2019    10
```

Table: receive

```
tranId   roll       month       amount
1       1111    October-2019    10
2       1111    September-2019  10
3       1113    October-2019    10
4       1114    October-2019    10
5       1115    October-2019    10
6       1116    October-2019    10
7       1117    October-2019    10
8       1118    October-2019    10
9       1119    October-2019    10
10      1120    October-2019    10
```

In both table month columns are string & table receive roll+month column is unique.  i want to create a receivable & receive statement report of a student (Where roll=1111) from those table like.

Expected result:

```
month           rcvamount   rcvvmonth      rcvvamount
---------------------------------------------------------
October-2019       10       October-2019    10
---------------------------------------------------------
September-2019     10           -                -
```

my query is:

```
SELECT receive.month, sum(receive.amount) AS rcvamount, receivable.month AS rcvvmonth,
       receivable.amount AS rcvvamount
FROM receive
    LEFT JOIN receivable ON receive.month = receivable.month
WHERE receive.roll = 1111
GROUP BY receive.month
```

and resutl is:

```
month           rcvamount   rcvvmonth      rcvvamount
----------------|-------|----------------------------------
October-2019    |   50  |       October-2019    10
----------------|-------|----------------------------------
September-2019     10           -                -
```

revamount in October-2019 should be 10 from receive table.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate *before* joining.  Or use `union all` and aggregate:

```
SELECT month, SUM(ramount) AS rcvamount, 
       SUM(raamount) AS rcvvamount
FROM ((SELECT month, amount as ramount, null as raamount
       FROM receive
       WHERE roll = 1111
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT month, NULL as ramount, amount as raamount
       FROM receiveable
       WHERE roll = 1111
      )
     ) r
GROUP BY month;
```

One nice feature of `UNION ALL` is that it handles missing data in either table.

Comment: If i receive 1 more amount in October-2019 it's adding same amount in receivable side. Examp.: add October-2019 amount 10 then it's show                                 `month               rcvamount rcvvamount `
`October-2019           20       20` 
`September-2019  10      10 `